# Enemy HP not going down in batch RPG game

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to make a batch RPG game from scratch, but I'm stuck at a pretty big problem. Whenever I attack the enemy wolf, my HP goes down, but the wolfs HP doesn't.

```
:fight1
set wolfhp=45
set wolfdmg=3
cls
echo You are fighting a wolf.
echo.
echo Your health: %playerhp%
echo.
echo Your attack: %playerdmg%
echo.
echo.
echo Enemy health: %wolfhp%
echo.
echo Enemy attack: %wolfdmg%
echo.
echo What is your next move?
echo.
echo 1. Attack
echo 2. Spells
echo 3. Flee
echo.
set /p input=C:\
if "%input%" == "1" goto fight1attack
if "%input%" == "2" goto spells
if "%input%" == "3" goto game
goto fight1

:fight1attack
set /a playerhp-=%wolfdmg%
set /a wolfhp-=%playerdmg%
if %wolfhp% lss 1 goto victory1
if %playerhp% lss 1 goto defeat
goto fight1
```

Above is where the problem persists (most likely). I don't see anything wrong with the code at all. My damage and health variables are set somewhere else, but that isn't an issue because it stills shows my stats where it says.

```
echo Your health: %playerhp%
echo.
echo Your attack: %playerdmg%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `set wolfhp` and `set wolfdmp` commands appear *after* the `:fight1` label which you jump back to after every turn. This resets both variables to their initial values after every turn by re-running the `set` command.

You should move your `:fight1` label to after you've declared your variables using `set`, so they aren't reset each turn:

```
set wolfhp=45
set wolfdmg=3
:fight1
cls
...
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I can't believe I overlooked that.

Comment: @AutonomousVariable No problem! Please remember to mark answers as *Accepted* if they've helped you so that the question shows up as solved.